# Zoom a NSTextView and preserve word wrap in Swift 2

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview

Is there a way to zoom the contents of a NSTextView (rich text) **keeping the font size the same** that also **preserves the word wrap to the dimensions of the window**?

Why I need to do this:

Users should be able to write rich text that they can zoom in on without affecting the contents of the document itself, while still wrapping to the same size of the window. This would make it easy to adjust the overall zoom level if the user is having a hard time reading the text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure it out--learned a lot since I originally asked the question. Coordinate conversion, bugs, and many other things must be taken into consideration:

```
//
//  ZoomingTextView.swift
//
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239926/zoom-a-nstextview-and-preserve-word-wrap-in-swift-2
// Joseph E.
//
// Use/modify to your convenience

import Cocoa

class ZoomingTextView : NSTextView {

    /// 100% 1x1 unit scaling:
    let unitSize: NSSize = NSSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)

    /// The last scaling factor that this textview experienced
    private(set) var oldScaleFactor: Double = 1.0

    /// The current zoom factor
    private(set) var zoomFactor: Double = 1.0

    /// Zooms to the specified scaling factor.
    /// - Parameter factor: The scaling factor. 1.0 = 100%
    func zoomTo(factor: Double) {
        var scaleFactor = factor

        // No negative values:
        if scaleFactor < 0 {
            scaleFactor = abs(scaleFactor)
        }

        // No 0 value allowed!
        if scaleFactor == 0.0 {
            scaleFactor = 1.0
        }

        // Don't repeatedly zoom in on 100%
        // Prevents glitches
        if (scaleFactor < 1.01 && scaleFactor > 0.99) {
            // we'll only reach here if scale factor is about 1.0
            if (oldScaleFactor < 1.01 && oldScaleFactor > 0.99) {
                // print("old and new scale factor are 1.0")
                // For some reason, if we try to set the zoom to 100% when the zoom is
                // already 100%, everything disappears. This prevents that from
                // happening.
                return
            }
        }

        // Don't do redundant scaling:
        if scaleFactor == oldScaleFactor {
            // We've already scaled.
            return
        }


        // Reset the zoom before re-zooming
        scaleUnitSquareToSize(convertSize(unitSize, fromView: nil))

        // Perform the zoom on the text view:
        scaleUnitSquareToSize(NSSize(width: scaleFactor, height: scaleFactor))


        // Handle the details:
        let tc = textContainer!
        let lm = layoutManager!

        // To make word-wrapping update:
        let scrollContentSize = enclosingScrollView!.contentSize

        // Necessary for word wrap
        frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: scrollContentSize.width, height: 0.0)

        tc.containerSize = NSMakeSize(scrollContentSize.width, CGFloat.max)
        tc.widthTracksTextView = true
        lm.ensureLayoutForTextContainer(tc)

        // Scroll to the cursor! Makes zooming super nice :)
        alternativeScrollToCursor()

        needsDisplay = true

        zoomFactor = scaleFactor

        // Keep track of the old scale factor:
        oldScaleFactor = scaleFactor
    }

    /// Forces the textview to scroll to the current cursor/caret position.
    func alternativeScrollToCursor() {
        if let cursorPosition: NSInteger = selectedRanges.first?.rangeValue.location {
            scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location: cursorPosition, length: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Two issues: First, the `frame` variable isn’t actually used, this generates a warning. Second, the text is not actually wrapped all the time; sometimes, the layout gets stuck at a certain width. Changing the text view’s width causes layout again. There is a fix: Use `textContainerChangedGeometry()` instead of `ensureLayoutForTextContainer()`.

Comment: Thank you Martin. It's horribly out-of-date and written before I did this for a living. My original project that this was built for won't compile anymore so it's hard to salvage it.

Comment: No worries. I was simply looking for some inspiration about this problem and used your code as a starting point. I thought it might be nice to add this correction for the benefit of people finding this in the future :)